# Перенаправление stdout и stderr и на экран и в файл

Tags: unix, sh

Как в начале скрипта перенаправить вывод в файл и на экран одновременно?

Comment: В итоге: в чистой unix системе, без плагинов и доп. софта не получается одной командой выводить stdout и stderr в файл. Поэтому вызываю скрипт из другого скрипта: `./sript.sh &>>$log`

Comment: я дополнил ответ для того случая, если вам уже не надо «и на экран». никаких «плагинов и доп.софта», естественно, не требуется. а вот использованная вами конструкция `&>` (с вариациями), насколько мне известно, в стандарте posix как раз и не упомянута.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

написанное ниже справедливо, насколько я знаю, лишь для «продвинутых» оболочек типа *gnu/bash* и *zsh*.

---

для перенаправления всего, что будут выдавать команды, выполняющиеся внутри скрипта, в файл (вдобавок к выводу на терминал), можно использовать команду [`exec`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17974.html) в комплекте с программой `tee`.

если требуется записывать в файл `file` только то, что команды скрипта будут выдавать в *stdout*, можно написать так:

```
exec > >(tee file)
command1
command2
```

если же требуется записывать в файл и то, что отправляется в *stderr*, то надо добавить перенаправление `2>&1`:

```
exec > >(tee file) 2>&1
command1
command2
```

---

**дополнение по поводу просто вывода в файл обоих потоков полностью posix-совместимым образом**

и *stdout* и *stderr*, в которые выведут информацию команды, будут записаны в *file*:

```
exec >file 2>&1
command1
command2
```

а так *file* будет дополнен (а не перезаписан, как в предыдущем примере):

```
exec >>file 2>&1
command1
command2
```

Comment: Кстати, а как это отменить? То есть как вернуть stdout и stderr к умолчальному поведению?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, изнутри этого скрипта? ну, наверно, через файловые дескрипторы родительского процесса (его *pid* находится в переменной окружения `PPID`). как-нибудь так: `echo текст > /proc/$PPID/fd/1` (здесь `1` — это *stdout*).

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна команда `tee`.

```
echo foo | tee foo.txt
```

Синтаксис:

```
tee [ -a ] [ -i ] [ filename ... ]

-a Не переписывать файл, а добавить строки
-i Игнорировать ошибки
```

Есть ещё команда со смешным именем `pee` — так же, только для pipe'ов.

Comment: Не получается ничего толкового через tee - по-прежнему вывод идет только на экран. Хотя в инете все пишут, что работает.

Comment: @ОлегС а как вы пробовали? покажите код?

Comment: """#!/bin/sh
source_system="/home/test/get_data.sh"
log_file="/home/test/"`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S`".log"
$source_system | tee -a $log_file
ls asfasffasasffas | tee -a $log_file"""
 каталога `asfasffasasffas` нет, а ошибка идет в консоль.