# Перенаправить поток вывода в файл

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

как перенаправить stdout в файл?

например, я ввожу:

```
touch test.txt // и тут, как я понял, должно быть 0< log.txt
```

но не работает.

---

из комментариев:

например я хочу что бы эта команда "ls -laRf" записалась в файл. Потом мне нужно будет другую команду записать, например, "grep "include" text.txt"

Comment: touch только создает файл / меняет дату модификации, перенаправление ввода ничего не даст, т.к. данная команда стандартный ввод не читает

Comment: @Mike а синтаксис вообще правильный?

Comment: @Mike у меня записывает в файл то должно быть в выводе, а я хотел бы получить запись команд

Comment: так вообще не ясно, что значит перенаправить stdin В файл. я бы понял, если "взять stdin ИЗ файла" или "перенаправить stdout в файл"

Comment: запись  каких команд ? поступающих на вход к чему ? shell ведут логи команд, каждый shell в своем файле, например bash в `.bash_history`

Comment: @Mike например я хочу что бы эта команда "ls -laRf" записалась в файл. Потом мне нужно будет другую команду записать например "grep "include" text.txt"

Comment: а вам надо что бы команда при этом выполнилась ? можно же просто `echo ls -laRf >>file.txt` ну или с выполнением, что то типа `echo  ls -laRf | tee file.txt | /bin/sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

записать стандартный вывод (stdout) команды в файл:

```
$ команда > файл
```

добавить стандартный вывод (stdout) команды к содержимому файла:

```
$ команда >> файл
```

записать и стандартный вывод (stdout) и вывод ошибок (stderr) команды в файл:

```
$ команда &> файл
```

добавить и стандартный вывод (stdout) и вывод ошибок (stderr) команды к содержимому файла:

```
$ команда &>> файл
```

---

можно записывать в файл не только вывод команды, но и вообще всё, что вы вводите, и видите в терминале. для этого можно воспользоваться программой `script`.

она запускает новый экземпляр оболочки, и всё, что вы вводите, и всё, что получаете в ответ, сохраняет в указанный ей параметром файл. если этот файл не указывать, по умолчанию будет использоваться файл с именем `typescript` в текущем каталоге. завершить работу оболочки (и, соответственно, прервать выполнение программы `script`) можно, как и обычно, командой `exit` (часто оболочки настроены выполнять ту же команду при получении клавиатурного сочетания <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd>).

пример:

```
$ script logfile
Script started, file is logfile
$ какие-нибудь команды
$ exit
```

теперь всё, что вы видели при выполнении `какие-нибудь команды`, можно посмотреть в файле `logfile`. например, с помощью программы `less`. а чтобы правильно отобразились и спец-символы, служащие для цветовой раскраски, программе `less` надо передать опцию `-R`:

```
$ less -R logfile
```

Comment: И если нужно перенаправить вывод сразу от блока кода, то удобно использовать решение отсюда: [Перенаправление stdout и stderr и на экран и в файл](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489152/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-stdout-%d0%b8-stderr-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)